# Selecionar valor desejado com REGEX para dois padrões diferentes

Tags: python, regex

Eu tenho a seguinte entrada de dados:

```
INSTANCE-hostname:Sys
INSTANCE-hostname-INSTANCE_00:Ins
```

Sempre irá seguir este caso, onde somente o que me interessa é o valor `hostname`, ou seja, meu OUTPUT deve ser:

```
hostname
hostname
```

Testei com o regex `[^-]*-([^:]+)`, mas está falhando:

**[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/QFCqhB/3)**

**[PYTHEX](https://pythex.org/)**

Como obter a saída desejada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua regex falha porque você só verifica os casos em que há `:` depois de `hostname`. Mas você precisa verificar também se tem um `-`:

```
import re

textos = [ 'INSTANCE-hostname:Sys', 'INSTANCE-hostname-INSTANCE_00:Ins' ]

r = re.compile(r'^[^-]+-([^-:]+)[-:]')
for texto in textos:
    m = r.match(texto)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

O [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` indica que vou começar a busca pelo início da string.

A regex busca por vários caracteres que não são hífen (`[^-]+`), seguido de um hífen, seguido de vários caracteres que não sejam hífen nem dois pontos (`[^-:]+`), seguido de um hífen ou dois pontos (`[-:]`).

A parte que eu quero pegar (logo após o primeiro hífen) está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Em seguida, eu posso pegar esse grupo usando `group(1)` (eu uso `1` porque é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, e portanto é o primeiro grupo).

A saída é:

```
hostname
hostname
```

---

Se a parte correspondente a "hostname" sempre será "uma ou mais letras", dá para usar também:

```
r = re.compile(r'^[^-]+-([a-zA-Z]+)[-:]')
```

Isso pode dar resultados diferentes, dependendo das strings que você usar, já que  `[^-:]+` considera **quaisquer** caracteres que não sejam `-` ou `:` (ou seja, quebras de linha, números, sinais de pontuação, espaços, etc). Mas se usar `[a-zA-Z]`, você restringe somente ao que precisa (o ideal em regex é tentar, na medida do possível, [dizer exatamente o que você quer e o que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want)).

Comment: ficou muito boa sua resposta, consegui entender exatamente onde meu regex estava falhando, muito obrigado pela ajuda e por ter formulado o script em python junto com o regex !!

Comment: @LuisV. Só lembrando que se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Comment: Vou aceitar sim, so estou aguardando terminar o tempo, ainda esta bloqueado para aceitar respostas!

Comment: @LuisV. Ah é, esqueci que tinha esse tempo mínimo pra aceitar... :-)

Comment: Feito, muito obrigado !!

Comment: so uma duvida, quando eu tiver o seguinte caso 'INSTANCE-hostname_INSTANCE_00:Ins', o regex acima se aplica?

Comment: @LuisV. Não, vc vai ter que adicionar o `_` na lista: https://regex101.com/r/QHgxpD/1/

Comment: Perfeito, entendi, muito obrigado mesmo, esclareceu todas minhas duvidas !!